# Non-breaking space in Flutter string interpolation

Tags: flutter, string-interpolation, character-codes

From time to time I need a non-breaking space in my Flutter Text widgets, e.g. a "Show more" link or a number with unit like "50 km/h".

The following code works fine but it looks overly complicated:

```
const int $nbsp = 0x00A0; // from https://pub.dev/packages/charcode

print('Hello${String.fromCharCode($nbsp)}World'); // --> prints "Hello World", does not break
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ :/
```

I'm curious if there is a shorter way to use an integer constant from the [charcode package](https://pub.dev/packages/charcode) in my interpolated string?

Comment: It doesn't answer your question directly, but you can always extract that part to a variable so that the code will be more clear :)

Comment: Yes of course. I just thought I might be missing something essential when working with the integer constants. If it turns out that `String.fromCharCode` is the intended way to use them, you can post your comment as an answer in a few days and I will happily accept it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The best solution I have come up with is creating a String extension method.

```
// string_extension.dart

const int $nbsp = 0x00A0;

extension StringExtension on String {
  String get nonBreaking => replaceAll(' ', String.fromCharCode($nbsp));
}
```

Usage example:

```
// import 'string_extension.dart';

Text('Hello World'.nonBreaking)
```

Comment: This is the BEST solution. Bravo dear sir.

Answer (score 23):

The easy way to do it is using escape combination [\u{00A0}]:

```
Text('Hello\u{00A0}world');
```

Comment: Is there any way to use it with an integer variable like `$nbsp` from the charcode package?